# Nullpointer exception when I tried to upload a picture to firebase taken from the camera

Tags: android, firebase, camera, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload a picture taken from the camera and I got Nullpointer exception, here its the code:

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT  && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        uri= data.getData();
        mImagenIv.setImageURI(uri);

        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"si señor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    } else if(requestCode == CAMERA_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Bitmap  bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
       Uri uri= data.getData();
        mImagenIv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {


                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"si señor",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The thing its that when I use the same code when I select a picture from the storage that code its working as expected.The null pointer I got its on the following line:

```
StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("fotos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Could someone helpme with that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `startActivityForResult()` call for `CAMERA_INTENT` is using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, `data.getData()` should always return `null`. If `Bitmap  bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` is working, that `Bitmap` is your photo. You will need to get that to Firebase by one means or another. If the Firebase API does not accept a `Bitmap`, you may have to use `compress()` to write that `Bitmap` to some temporary file to use with Firebase.

Comment: hi, first of all thanks for the answer, yeah as you are saying bitmap its working because its filling the imageview properly, how can I use that compress method properly to upload to firebase.

Comment: @Gastondelacruz: `compress()` takes an `OutputStream`. Create a `FileOutputStream` on some temporary file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`). Use that file for your upload. Delete the temporary file when the upload is complete.